# Protractor hard to click popup/dropdown

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-node, jasmine2.0

Hey guys I am trying to click on an element called practitioner access on my company's web site and I have tried looking up documentation on stack over flow and have not figured out how to do this exactly I need help. What I am trying to do is click on the practitioner access popup/drop down and I have not been able to find the code to do it. Please see epic at the bottom:

[image]
This is how far I have gotten so far but protractor cant find the element

```
var pracaccess = element(by.xpath("//contains(@onclick, 'Practitioner Access')"))
pracaccess.click();
browser.sleep(10000);
```

I have tried to use these site to try and help myself but I can't piece it together. Any help would be appreciated. I am new to xpath as well.

---

new info to possibly help: 
Here is a more expanded view

[image]

Also this is what it looks like in vb-script but its basically the same any suggestions?

```
Browser("ADP_2").Page("ADP_3").Link("html tag:=A","innertext:=Practitioner Access").WaitProperty "visible",True,30000
        Browser("ADP_2").Page("ADP_3").Link("html tag:=A","innertext:=Practitioner Access").Object.Click
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath expression would look for a tag with the `contains` tag name, which does not exist. Instead, you've actually meant:

```
//a[contains(@onclick, 'Practitioner Access')]
```

Or, there is a nicer way to locate an `a` element by the link text:

```
element(by.linkText("Practitioner Access"))
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this out and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

The answer by alecxe is correct but if you want it to be as xpath:

```
element(by.xpath('//a[text()="Practitioner Access"]'));
```

Comment: Hey I tried this and for some reason protractor is saying cant find Practitioner Access and other suggestions. i tried linktext and xpath

Comment: Okay this is my fault this actually works my problem was i need to allow time for the Practitioner Access drop-down to become visible so i did browser.sleep 2000 and it was able to click it. thanks.